# appsettings.{Env}.json hierarchy in ASP.NET Core 6

Tags: asp.net-core, hierarchy, appsettings

Overwriting the default `appsettings.json` with your `appsettings.{myEnv}`.json in ASP.NET 6 [is easy.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-6.0) But is there a way to have a deeper level of hierarchy?

Consider this specific example.

Given: `appsettins.json`, `appsettings.Env1.json`, `appsettings.Env2.json`

If I'm in Env1, I want `appsettings.json` to be overwritten by `appsettings.Env1.json` [(again, this is easy.)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-6.0).

Now I want that the following happens, when I am in Env2:

1. **load** `appsettings.json`
2. **overwrite** with `appsettings.Env1.json`
3. **overwrite** with `appsettings.Env2.json`

**Background** (*optional reading*)

Why is this useful? Well, imagine you have two different testing environments, where the difference are only a few settings but otherwise, there are hundred of lines in the appsettings, then you would have to maintain plenty of duplicate config code. You could delete almost half of it, if you could simply introduce hierarchy

I tried to find a solution in [Microsoft's documentation on Configuration in ASP.NET Core](https://stackoverflow.com) but this case is not covered.

Comment: But `Env2` wouldn't know about `Env1` so how could it load those config values?

Comment: You have to use two separate environment variable keys.

Comment: `Env2` does not know that a variable `Env1` might exist but we have all three files in one place

Comment: .NET settings already have such a hierarchy. Settings can be loaded from any valid source with newer settings overriding previous ones. You can have one big settings file and override specific ones through extra files, environment variables, command-line settings

Answer (score 2):

You could use your own environment variables (instead of `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT`) and do something like this:

```cs
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

var env1 = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("TESTING_ENVIRONMENT_1");
var env2 = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("TESTING_ENVIRONMENT_2");

if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(env1))
{
    builder.Configuration.AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env1}.json",
            optional: true,
            reloadOnChange: true);

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(env2))
    {
        builder.Configuration.AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env2}.json",
                optional: true,
                reloadOnChange: true);
    }
}
```

or set the environment variable values as delimited string:

`TESTING_ENVIRONMENT: ENV1;ENV2`

```cs
var testingEnvironment = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("TESTING_ENVIRONMENT");

if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(testingEnvironment))
{
    foreach (var env in testingEnvironment.Split(';'))
    {
        builder.Configuration.AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env}.json",
                optional: true,
                reloadOnChange: true);
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a bit risky. Someone could modify the environment variable and cause the application to load bad settings. `IHostingEnvironment.EnvironmentName` validates the values stored in `DOTNET_ENVIRONMENT` and only returns one of the predefined values.

Comment: I would argue that if someone is able to modify the server's environment variables then it's already too late. Security has been compromised and appsettings is the least of your problems. The "hacker" might as well modify the appsettings file itself instead of changing the environment.

Answer (score 1):

You can add settings from any file (or source) you want. Later sources override previous ones. There's nothing special about `appsettings.json` or `appsettings.Development.json`. These names are the defaults added by `Host.CreateDefaultBuilder`.

By default, settings can be loaded from the command line or environment variables. The settings `Environment` is loaded from the `DOTNET_ENVIRONMENT` env variable for example

The only special part is that the environment name, available through `IHostingEnvironment.EnvironmentName`, is validated to ensure it doesn't contain any unexpected values, eg `MyMalware` that would allow loading unexpected settings by adding an `appsettings.MyMalware.json` file.

**Extra Files**

For example, you can add `.AddJsonFile("myExtrastuff.json")` or `AddXmlFile("vintagesettings.xml")` to load extra settings. The examples in [Configuration Providers in .NET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/configuration-providers) show examples for all built-in file providers.

You could add different settings per operating system (Linux, Windows) base on the [Environment.OSVersion](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.osversion?view=net-7.0) value
:

```
using IHost host = Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
    .ConfigureAppConfiguration((hostingContext, configuration) =>
    {

        var os=Environment.OSVersion.Platform;

        configuration
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.{os}.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true);
```

You could combine OS and environment as well

```
using IHost host = Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
    .ConfigureAppConfiguration((hostingContext, configuration) =>
    {
        IHostEnvironment env = hostingContext.HostingEnvironment;
        var os=Environment.OSVersion.Platform;

        configuration
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.{os}.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true);
```

You can construct the file name using other environment variables too, but you should take care to validate the env variable contents to prevent attacks. One way to do that is to define the allowed values in an `enum`, eg :

```
public enum Env1
{
    Value1,
    Value2
}

var envText=Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("MY_SPECIAL_VARIABLE");
if(Enum.TryParse(envText, out var env1))
{
    configuration
        .AddJsonFile("appsettings.{env1}.json", optional: true);
}
```

**Loading from Environment Variables**

You can load settings from individual environment variables whose name starts with a specific prefix, eg `MYPREFIX_`:

```
builder.Configuration.AddEnvironmentVariables(prefix: "MYPREFIX_");
```

After that, double underscores are translated into `:`.

Let's say you want to override the RabbitMQ username in your `appsettings.json` file when you deploy to Kubernetes or Docker:

```
{
    "RabbitMQ": {
        "User":"guest"
    }
}
```

You can't change a Docker image after deployment or every time a password changes. In such cases it's common to pass such settings as environment variables to the application. To do so, you can define the `MYPREFIX_RabbitMQ__User` environment variable to `mylimiteduser`.

To load that value, you treat `RabbitMQ` as a section and `User` as a key:

```
var usern=configuration.GetSection("RabbitMQ").GetValue("User");
```

The environment variable will override the `guest` value with `mylimiteduser`

Comment: If what appsetting is ultimately taking effect is determined by which one was added last: what is this method for then: `builder.UseEnvironment("Env1")`?

Comment: The configuration middleware is separate from the host builder. In `builder.UseEnvironment` you're telling the `HostBuilder` which environment to pass to the configuration middleware. This will affect the `IHostEnvironment.EnvironmentName` value. If you add your own custom settings (not appsettins, they can come from databases and XML files too), they'll override anything you've already loaded.

Comment: This allows you to build any hierarchy you want. The default one can handle many scenarios: the general appsettings can be overriden by environment-specific files, which can be overriden by environment variables and finally by command-line arguments. This would allow you to tweak eg run the same application with different settings just once by specifying them as CLI parameters, or by modifying the environment variables in a single terminal session

Comment: You could also deploy your app to Kubernetes and pass sensitive settings as env variables from the orchestrator to the pod